# Change method on a Time class is not working Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, time, fullcalendar

So I have this an event that i use with fullcalendar-rails. I dont want to use a datetime format because it automatically creates a date selector for both variable(and fullcalendar needs to receive date/time). I would rather have a date selector and 2 time selectors. So i tried doing that but the time_selector will automatically generate a default date.

So I look at the class Time docs and I found that there is a method called change http://apidock.com/rails/Time/change. So, every thing works but it just wont modify the default date of the time selector to the date of the date selector?? But when I try it in my console it works perfectly..? Very confuse any help would be greatly appreciated Thank.

**Events controller**

```
def create  
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @event = @user.events.new(event_params)
    @event.user_id = @user.id
    @event.save
    respond_with(@event)
  end
```

**Event.rb**

```
before_save :date_setter

  def date_setter
    data = self.date
    self.start = self.start.change(:year => data.year, :month => data.month, :day => data.day)
  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@event, url: :user_events) do |f| %>
  <% if @event.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this event from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :position %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :position %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :start %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :end %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: not quite unserstood , where is the problem, is it in the `before_save` action?

Comment: Actually the problem is that its not doing anything its still giving me the default date when a time is created instead of swapping it with the date that the user selected with the date selector. So its as if its not running my date_setter definition. But im not getting any error its just not swapping the date for the inputed date.

Comment: so you wish to say that the code `self.start = self.start.change` isn't work, and `self.start` has which value after save?

Comment: Yes exectly after it saves I get 2000-01-01 12:09:00 UTC. Where '2000-01-01' is the generated date for the time. But the date selected on my date selector is '2015-01-15'.

Comment: what are the values of `self.start` and `self.date` during save?

Comment: The value are whatever the user has inputed after hitting submit. So for event for date I picked ' 2015-01-02' and for start(time) I selected '12:09'

Comment: add pry gem,  and insert line `require 'pry';binding.pry` at the edn of the `date_setter`, and on breakpoint stop just inspect the `self` value, and dates

Comment: Ok so I used pry. self.start is actually has the correct date but it is just not saving into the database. its as if it does the changes then just does not save once done.

Comment: Then in the pry, you are able to check wheither the field is correctly stored within record.save()? Seems there is an additional hook that sets the `start` to default